# Identify the top processes when the overall system has large CPU utilization in Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cpu-usage, top

I have a Ubuntu server running in EC2.

Occasionally, I get a large CPU usage 99+% utilization as measured in EC2 monitoring dashboard, even though most times it is less than 10%.

Since traffic to my site is spiky, and many times happens at the middle of the night, I could not login and use top at that time.

What is the best way to monitor which processes is using the CPU when the load spikes up?

One option I can think of is, dump top output every few seconds to a file.

However, is there a better option to monitor CPU and memory hungry processes?

Comment: You can always use some monitoring tools like elk stack zabbix and others

Comment: suggest also [giving sshd a high priority](https://serverfault.com/questions/938350/how-can-sshd-be-configured-to-have-high-cpu-priority/938351#938351) to ensure you can get a login.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

> sar
>   [Useful Sar (Sysstat) Examples](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/sar-examples/)

willbe that thing what You looking for.

or pidstat

> [Linux pidstat Command: Get Statistics For Individual Tasks / Process](https://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-monitor-process-using-pidstat/)

Comment: Sar does not report on individual processes.