# How can sshd be configured to have high CPU priority

Tags: ssh, systemd

When a server is overloaded, what is a way under systemd to give ssh a high priority to ensure a remote ssh connection gets a priority to resolve the critical situation?

Comment: What kind of load are you talking about? CPU will likely not be the problem, even if SSH only gets a fraction of CPU time. More likely a problem is load caused by iowait and/or swapping. Solving this requires more than just setting a priority.

Comment: So [IOSchedulingPriority=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#IOSchedulingPriority=)1?

Comment: It's not quite that simple, especially if the machine is virtualized. Simulate some IO with benchmark tools and see what happens.

Answer (score 9):

Create a systemd override file setting the nice level to a high negative priority (maximum is -20, however some kernel processes require that for integrity).

```
/etc/systemd/system/ssh.service.d/nice_high.conf 

[Service]
Nice=-15
```

Run `systemctl daemon-reload` for this to have an effect.