# Python pip installing grpcio kills connections to my Google Compute Instance?

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, pip

I'm seeing a strange issue when I try to install the Pip package "**google-cloud-datastore**" where once it starts building the dependent "grcpio" wheel, all TCP (including SSH) connections to the instance become unusable, and all subsequent SSH connections timeout, even from the Cloud Console.

After leaving the SSH terminal open for 10 minutes after running pip, the last lines never change from the following:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: grpcio
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for grpcio ... |
```

The instance responds to ICMP pings as if nothing happened but the only way to connect is to reset it from the Cloud Console.

The instance is an **f1-micro (1 vCPU, 0.6 GB memory)** running in region **us-central1-b**. Entire pip output can be found [in this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Wr7UnAX7)

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

Running as root and High CPU usage for compiling with "cc1plus" was stalling the instance.

This was not immediately obvious as the Console CPU graph scales as a percentage out of 1.0, not 100 and the CPU had bursted above 1.0

[image]

I worked around this by changing the [sshd nice value to higher priority](https://serverfault.com/questions/938350/how-can-sshd-be-configured-to-have-high-cpu-priority)